# converting nvarchar to int error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query that I can't quite work out the error I'm getting.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1.5' to data type int.

This is due to `pvlaue` for one case pulling a '1.5' string and trying to convert it to an int implicitly. I tried to rectify this by casting to a float but this doesn't seem to work for me. Any help in this regard would be very helpful.

I'm running this on SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

```
BEGIN DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Item = 'Water'

SELECT 
    d.DESCRIPTION, d.ITEM_CODE,  
    el.ENUM_LABEL as Building_Block, 
    CAST(itpC.pvalue AS DECIMAL(22, 3)), ffi.where_used,
    d.STATUS_IND
FROM 
    FSITEM d
LEFT JOIN 
    FSITEMTECHPARAM itp ON d.ITEM_CODE = itp.ITEM_CODE 
                        AND itp.PARAM_CODE = 'BUILDING_BLOCK'
LEFT JOIN 
    FSVALIDENUMVALCF ev ON CAST(coalesce(itp.PVALUE, 0) as float) = CAST(ev.ENUM_VALUE AS FLOAT)
                        AND ev.ENUM_CODE = 'C_BUILDING_BLOCK_TYP'
LEFT JOIN 
    FSVALIDENUMLABELCF el ON ev.ENUM_CODE = el.ENUM_CODE 
                          AND ev.ENUM_ORDER = el.ENUM_ORDER 
                          AND el.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'EN-US'
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         item_Code, max(CAST(pvalue AS FLOAT)) as pvalue
     FROM 
         FSITEMTECHPARAM
     JOIN
         KC_SITE_COST_MAP ON FSITEMTECHPARAM.PARAM_CODE = 'COST_'+KC_SITE_COST_MAP.COST_CODE
     GROUP BY 
         ITEM_CODE

     UNION

     SELECT
         ITEM_CODE, CAST(pvalue AS FLOAT) as pvalue
     FROM  
         FSFORMULA
     JOIN
         FSFORMULATECHPARAM ON FSFORMULA.FORMULA_ID = FSFORMULATECHPARAM.FORMULA_ID
                            AND PARAM_CODE = 'COST_TOTAL_BASE'
     WHERE 
         FSFORMULA.FORMULA_ID IN (SELECT FORMULA_ID FROM FSITEM)) itpC ON D.item_code = itpC.item_code
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         ffi.item_code, COUNT(distinct ffi.formula_id) where_used 
     FROM
         fsformulaingred ffi 
     JOIN
         fsformula ff ON ffi.formula_id = ff.formula_id 
     WHERE
         ff.status_ind = 500 AND ff.logical_delete = 0  
     GROUP BY
         ffi.item_code) ffi ON D.item_code = ffi.item_code 
WHERE 
    d.LOGICAL_DELETE = 0 
    AND d.COMPONENT_IND <> 2 
    AND d.Status_IND < 600
    AND (((CAST(ev.ENUM_VALUE as FLOAT) = 3 or CAST(ev.ENUM_VALUE as FLOAT) = 2)  
    AND d.Status_Ind < 600) OR
       CAST(ev.ENUM_VALUE as FLOAT) = 1 or CAST(ev.ENUM_VALUE as FLOAT) = '0') 
    AND (d.Description Like @Item + '%')
    --Or d.Description Like replace(@Item, '!', '%'))
ORDER BY 
    CAST(coalesce(ev.enum_value,0) as FLOAT) DESC, status_ind DESC, d.Item_Code
END
```

Comment: What result do you get when you try to cast it to `float`?

Comment: I get the error mention above where it still seems to try to convert to an int. even with the cast to a float.

Comment: Locale settings may get in your way here (e.g. if the decimal point should be a comma for CAST to work). You should also avoid real/float unless you really intend to use floating-point arithmetic. Try both `CAST('1.5' AS DECIMAL(38,7))` and `CAST('1,5' AS DECIMAL(38,7))` in a simple select. Also make sure there are no unprintable characters in the text (which might not show up in error messages); you can cast to `VARBINARY(MAX)` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `coalesce` that is doing the conversion to `int`, so casting the result from the `coalesce` is too late.

The result of an expression has to have the same type regardless of how the expression is evaluated. The expression `coalesce(itp.PVALUE, 0)` will be of the type `int` regardless of whether the value `itp.PVALUE` or the value `0` is used, because the type of `0` is `int`.

If you cast the `0` to `float`, the type of the expression will be `float`, so use `coalesce(itp.PVALUE, cast(0 as float))`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much.i have been staring at that for two days.